# Использование изображения вместо радио-кнопки

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Как я могу использовать изображение в опции пользовательского выбора вместо радио-кнопки? То есть, если пользователь щелкает по изображению, то оно должно вести себя как радио-кнопка.

**C радио кнопками:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Без радио кнопок:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подойдут реализации как при помощи jQuery, так и на чистом CSS.

Перевод вопроса: [Use Image instead of radio button @Vignesh Pichamani](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17541614/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-image-instead-of-radio-button/17541916#17541916

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Оберните **radio** и **image** в `<label>`
- **Спрячьте radio** кнопку
- Разместите изображение рядом с `hidden radio`, используя селектор
  [Adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)`+`

---

```
 <label>
      <input type="radio" name="fb" value="small" />
      <img src="fb1.jpg">
    </label>
```

**CSS:**

```
label > input{ /* HIDE RADIO */
  visibility: hidden; /* Makes input not-clickable */
  position: absolute; /* Remove input from document flow */
}
label > input + img{ /* IMAGE STYLES */
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid transparent;
}
label > input:checked + img{ /* (RADIO CHECKED) IMAGE STYLES */
  border:2px solid #f00;
}
```

Не забудьте добавить класс к вашим `labels`, а в `CSS` используйте этот класс.

### Пользовательские стили и анимации

Вот расширенная версия, использующая элемент `<i>` и `:after pseudo:`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body{color:#444;font:100%/1.4 sans-serif;}


/* CUSTOM RADIO & CHECKBOXES
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541916/383904 */
.rad,
.ckb{
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
.rad > input,
.ckb > input{ /* HIDE ORG RADIO & CHECKBOX */
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
/* RADIO & CHECKBOX STYLES */
.rad > i,
.ckb > i{     /* DEFAULT <i> STYLE */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:  16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 8px #fff;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: gray;
}
/* CHECKBOX OVERWRITE STYLES */
.ckb > i {
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.rad:hover > i{ /* HOVER <i> STYLE */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #fff;
  background: gray;
}
.rad > input:checked + i{ /* (RADIO CHECKED) <i> STYLE */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #fff;
  background: orange;
}
/* CHECKBOX */
.ckb > input + i:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  width:  12px;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  background: gray;
}
.ckb > input:checked + i:after{ /* (RADIO CHECKED) <i> STYLE */
  margin-left: 11px;
  background:  orange;
}
```

```html
<label class="rad">
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="a" />
  <i></i> Radio 1
</label>
<label class="rad">
  <input type="radio" name="r1" value="b" />
  <i></i> Radio 2
</label>

<br>

<label class="ckb">
  <input type="checkbox" value="a" />
  <i></i> Checkbox 1
</label>
<label class="ckb">
  <input type="checkbox" value="b" />
  <i></i> Checkbox 2
</label>
```

**[jsBin demo 2](http://jsbin.com/pafifi/3/edit?html,css,output)**

Перевод ответа:  [Use Image instead of radio button  @Roko C. Buljan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541916/7394871)